# Когда статическая свойсвто будет сброшено

Tags: c#, статистика

У меня есть абстрактный класс:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public static bool IsRunning { get; set; }

    public static void Start()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
    }
}
```

Как видно в методе Start я задаю true в IsRunning. Но по какой то причине свойства возврашает значение false. Я проверил, я никогда не задаю значение false. И в начале кода я задаю значение с помощью Start. Есть множество классов который наследовали этот класс. Вопрос, в данной ситуации в каком случаи IsRunning  возврашает занчение false?

Comment: _IsRunning возвращает значение false_ - до вызова метода `Start`

Answer (score -1):

Сразу после создания типа, происходит инициализация полей, в том числе и тех полей которые хранят значения автосвойства. А поле типа bool имеет значение по умолчанию - false.

Comment: Всмысле? Можете показать пример?

Comment: @DIlshod, пример чего ты хочешь увидеть?